# Heroku: efficient Images, Stylesheets and Javascripts Caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications, heroku

As far as I know, Rails3 can *"optimize"* the caching of images, javascripts, and style documents by appending a "?ID" string on the end of the filename, such as in: /stylesheets/normalize.css?1310531409.

However, if I use firebug to check my page's loading, here is what appears:
[image: GET normalize.css]

I am using RoR3 on Heroku, working on a Cedar Stack.

How can I manipulate the expiration time of the images/stylesheets/javacripts that are sent? Currently, they seem to expire in the moment they are sent, which is kind of non-sense. I am facing difficulties on accomplishing this on Heroku, operating on a Cedar Stack.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use [Jammit](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/), more specifically the [jammit-s3](https://github.com/benmyles/jammit-s3) gem. This will allow you to push your all assets to s3 and the linked gem has an s3 cache control setting. Used in combination with rails' asset_host configuration you can have an assets.yourdomain.com [subdomain](http://carltonbale.com/how-to-alias-a-domain-name-or-sub-domain-to-amazon-s3) which may help page load times and will reduce your slug size.

Comment: I'll give this a try, thanks for the advise. Those asset's HTTP expiry date should be easy to be set on amazon s3, right?

Comment: You set it in the assets.yml config file as described the foot of the jammit-s3 page linked. You can set it for 10 years for example and rails cache busting as described by idlefingers will respect changes and force browsers to download updated versions. Don't forget to ass your public directory to .slugignore.

Comment: Hey! it worked like a charm. Using **"s3_cache_control: public, max-age=<%= 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 %>"**. When I started looking at Jammit/Jammit-s3, I got a little scared, but it was really easy to set everything up. Only thing that is not working correctly is the jammit's automatic "javascript_compressor closure". But that was not the focus, I tried it just because I was already using closure on my own before. Well, whatever. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

The asset ID rails adds isn't to force caching, it's a cache buster. The numbers (by default) are the last modified date of the file. If you update the file, the numbers change, forcing browsers to get the new version. It doesn't mean that if the number is the same, the browser won't try to fetch it anyway.

Setting the expiry time is more in the domain of the server (presumably apache or nginx). You can configure them to have different cache control settings - a quick google for either will give you loads of tips for how to go about it.

Comment: Ahw, I see. Problem is I am using Heroku. Well, I'm going to try to discover how to accomplish so. Thanks very much.

Comment: According to the Heroku docs - http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-caching#static_assets - static assets should be cached for 12 hours. I've never really used Heroku for production, so can't really help more than that, sorry.

Comment: Yes.. I read that too... Unfortunately, they are cached for 0 seconds. :T If I discover what was wrong or what to do, I'll post it here :)